# Exporting Drive Letters to Columns

Tags: powershell, server, powershell-3.0

I am trying to get a list of drive letters to post to a CSV across the page not down,

EX:
systemname, Drive1,Drive2,Drive3,Drive4,Drive5

SVR,C:,D:,E:,F:

not

systemname,                                                                                deviceid
SVR,                                                                                    C:
SVR,                                                                                   D:
SVR,                                                                                    E:
SVR,                                                                                    F:

The code i put together and that has worked before for my other projects is

```
Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -filter "drivetype = '3'" -computername $serverlist[$j] | Select systemname, deviceid
```

Now there is more before to get the file with the computers in it and checking to make sure that it is online, but this being the meat I figure there has to be a way to do it, I just can't figure it out. any ideas?

Thanks,
Luke

Full Code

```
# Loop only executed when ping is successful
    if (test-connection -computername $serverlist[$j] -count 1 -quiet)
    {
        $results = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -filter "drivetype = '3'" -computername $serverlist[$j]
        "{0},{1}" -f $serverlist[$j], $results.deviceid -join "," | Add-Content c:\scripts\file.csv
        for ($k = 0; $k -lt $tempvar.count; $k++)
        {
            $tempoutput = $tempvar[$k]

            # Setup line to be written to file

            $exporttofile = $tempoutput.systemname + "," + $tempoutput.deviceid

            # Write to log, UTF8 encoding for .csv
            $exporttofile | out-file $logfile -append -encoding utf8
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is more to this code the simple answer appears to be just use `-join` in conjunction with something like `Add-Content` to set the line. Obviously you have this in some sort of loop structure which should not be affected here.

```powershell
$results = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -filter "drivetype = '3'" -computername $serverlist[$j]
"{0},{1}" -f $serverlist[$j],($results.deviceid -join ",") | Add-Content c:\temp\file.csv
```

Using the format operator we build a line with the server name and append a comma delimited string of the drive id's

Comment: That won't work because there is already a filter in that command.

Comment: @Luke Not sure exactly what you mean.... other than `Add-Content` is the better choice.

Comment: when I ran your code I got the error :"Get-WmiObject : Cannot bind parameter because parameter 'Filter' is specified more than once."

Comment: There is only one -filter in the code that Matt posted. What is the code that you are actually running that gives you that error?

Comment: I copied and pasted his code into ISE and ran it, if you look there is a -filter on the first line and a -f on the second.

Comment: The -f on the second line is the string format (-format) function. Not -Filter.

Comment: @EBGreen I understand that and to hopefully help you understand what I am seeing I added the full code up above in the question including the changes that Matt suggested.

Comment: @Luke The code I gave you is 2 different lines. You have them on the same line in your edit/

Comment: @Matt so the second line needs to be below the other and I can remove where I put it into the file since that is in yours?

Comment: @Luke My code is meant to replace from `[array]...` to the end of that inner for loop

Comment: Okay it is working now, except I am getting the following in the CSV, Server,System.Object[]

Comment: @Matt I updated the script above so you can see my current script with the corrections

Comment: @Luke that one is my bad. I added brackets around the second parameter to `-f`. See my edit.

Comment: @Matt That worked like a charm, sorry for the misunderstanding, and I would upvote your answer if I could, Thanks again